# How check document is available in xsl?

Tags: xslt

How i check `select="document('02.xml')/*/Person"/` and `select="document('04.xml')/*/Person"/` is available in xsl. when xsl is running

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/xmlResponse">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('02.xml')/*/Person"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('04.xml')/*/Person"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

*XSLT processor dependent.*

Check first the parser

```
<xsl:variable name="vendor" select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" />
```

and then make a choose.

**Microsoft** use embedded javascript custom function (http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=482), use FileSystemObject and returns 1 or 0 that can be then tested in XSLT.

**Saxon,Xalan:**

```
<xsl:variable name="d03" select="document('03.xml')"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$d03">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('03.xml')/*/Person"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
        <Person name="Matthew" missing="true"/>
</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
```