# xsl document test failing in IE8 and 9?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following in an XLST document

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:str="http://xsltsl.org/string" xmlns:dt="http://xsltsl.org/date-time" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
<xsl:if test="document('../folder/somefile.xml')">
    <!-- do stuff -->
</xsl:if>
```

In IE8 and IE9 attempting to process this file results in a JavaScript error,"The system cannot locate the object specified" - and the transform bugs out.

I have read about a 'doc-available' function in XLST2.0, but attempting to use it just gives me an error that the function is not available.

I have seen this question: [How check document is available in xsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212594/how-check-document-is-available-in-xsl) - but I'd prefer not to add processor dependent code, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something with 'doc-available'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [the XSLT 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) (and MSXML used by IE is an XSLT 1.0 processor) allows the XSLT processor do either "signal an error" or to continue by returning an empty node set if a `document()` call fails. Thus MSXML reporting an error is allowed and not a bug. You will need to make sure outside of XSLT that the file exists.